# Using this on objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm making a game, but I'm having trouble selling items.
I made the object

```
var price = {
sword:3,
fish:1
}
```

And once you click on something with class "item", it should tell you the price
Except It isn't working

```
$(".item").click(function(){
alert(price.(this.id))
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you post the html for `.item`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".item").click(function(){
alert(price[this.id]);
});
```

Comment: use like var price = {};
price.sword=3;
price.fish=1;  then use my solution

Comment: There's no need to change the way the object is created. This is the correct solution for accessing a dynamically named property on an object, so there's another reason it's not working. Possibly due to the scope of the `price` object, or some other reason.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the .click function was placed wrong, it works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
    alert(price.(this.id))
```

To

```
    alert(price[this.id])
```

You can't access object properties by dynamic names from dot notation, use subscript notation.

Answer (score 1):

access by

```
 alert(price[this.id]);
```